# Using iter.map, why does a closure work but passing the function directly does not?

Tags: rust, iterator, closures

I've got this function in Rust that capitalizes a string.

```rust
pub fn capitalize_first(input: &str) -> String {
    let mut c = input.chars();
    match c.next() {
        None => String::new(),
        Some(first) => first.to_uppercase().collect::<String>() + c.as_str(),
    }
}
```

Later, I use it to iterate over a vector of strings.

```rust
let words = vec!["hello", "world"];
let capitalized_words: Vec<String> =
    words.iter().map(|word| capitalize_first(word)).collect();
```

This works as expected, but I notice that the closure `|word| capitalize_first(word)` is pretty useless.  So I tried to replace it with passing `capitalize_first` directly like this.

```rust
let words = vec!["hello", "world"];
let capitalized_words: Vec<String> = words.iter().map(capitalize_first).collect();
```

This, however, fails to compile with the following error message.

```
10 | pub fn capitalize_first(input: &str) -> String {
   | ---------------------------------------------- found signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> _`
...
38 |         let capitalized_words: Vec<String> = words.iter().map(capitalize_first).collect();
   |                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected signature of `fn(&&str) -> _`
```

I'm having trouble understanding this error.  Why does the closure work but passing the function directly does not.  Is there something I can change that would allow me to pass the function reference instead of making a useless closure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you iterate over a collection like you are with your call to `words.iter()`, you are iterating over references to your elements. The elements in your vector are of type `&str`, and so references to your elements are of type `&&str`.

So `map` is expecting a function which takes an argument of type `&&str`, and so that is what the `word` argument in your closure is inferred as. Then when you call `capitalize_first` on `word`, it is automatically dereferenced to `&str`, due to the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait being implemented for all references.

However, even though your function will appear to accept arguments of type `&&str` due to this conversion, the conversion happens outside your function. So it doesn't mean that your function can be passed in place of a function which expects `&&str`.

There are 2 solutions. You can either change your function to be more generic, and have it accept anything that implements `AsRef<str>`. Then it will accept anything that can be dereferenced to `str`, which includes `&str`, `&&str` and `String`, among others.

```
pub fn capitalize_first<S: AsRef<str>>(input: S) -> String {
    let mut c = input.as_ref().chars();
    // Don't forget this ^

    match c.next() {
        None => String::new(),
        Some(first) => first.to_uppercase().collect::<String>() + c.as_str(),
    }
}
```

Or you can keep your function as it is, and fix it at the call site, by calling `copied()` on your iterator, which will essentially dereference the elements.

```
let capitalized_words: Vec<String> = words.iter().copied().map(capitalize_first).collect();
```

I would recommend the first approach.

Comment: I can across this problem when playing with the iterators2.rs exercise in Rustlings. It was quite surprising! Why do you recommend the `AsRef` solution?